# How to use Flutter Table_Calendar for previewing (Recurring System)

Tags: flutter

I'm tyring to apply a recurring system in flutter for my auditing system, where I can specify which week number I want the system to occur, for example:

I want the system to set the deadline for my auditing team at second week of every month.

Can I use table_calendar to achieve the preview. so when I select second week of every month. then the table_calendar will highlight the second week of every month (Previewing the next month schedule)

Is there other way to achieve something like this ? with other package maybe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **table_calendar** package along with some additional logic.

1. Create a `CalendarController` to control the calendar

   ```
   CalendarController _calendarController = CalendarController();
   ```
2. Define a function to highlight the second week of every month:

   ```
   void highlightSecondWeek(DateTime month) {
     DateTime firstDayOfMonth = DateTime(month.year, month.month, 1);
     DateTime secondWeekStart = firstDayOfMonth.add(Duration(days: 7 - firstDayOfMonth.weekday));
     DateTime secondWeekEnd = secondWeekStart.add(Duration(days: 6));

     _calendarController.setSelectedDayRange(secondWeekStart, secondWeekEnd);
   }
   ```
3. Use the TableCalendar widget and set the `calendarController` and `onVisibleDaysChanged` properties

   ```
   TableCalendar(
     calendarController: _calendarController,
     onVisibleDaysChanged: (first, last, format) {
       // Highlight the second week of the currently visible month
       highlightSecondWeek(first);
     },
   ),
   ```

In this example, the `highlightSecondWeek` function calculates the start and end dates of the second week in the given month and uses the `setSelectedDayRange` method of the `CalendarController` to highlight the corresponding days in the calendar. By setting the `onVisibleDaysChanged` callback, the second week will be highlighted whenever the visible month changes.